# How to redirect parent page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to ask you how to redirect parent page to a certain url from a pup up page? I tried several options as `parent` or `opener` and nothing is working. Please help me to understand what is wrong.

here is the code i used:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
  function openWin(){
       myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
       myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p> <button onclick=\"window.opener.location.href = ='http://www.google.com'; window.close();\">refresh</button>");
       myWindow.focus();
  }
</script>
</head>
<body>

   <input type="button" value="Open window" onclick="openWin()" />

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: You should be able to determine the problem yourself by using a browser's built-in debugging tools. If you have access to such a browser, open the developer tools console for the pop-up window and see what it says when you click on the button.

Comment: If you use chrome or firefox you can press F12 and see the error in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your code. Should be

```
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'myWindow'</p> <button onclick=\"window.opener.location.href = 'http://www.google.com'; window.close();\">refresh</button>");
```

i.e., remove the extra `=` before `'http://www.google.com'`.

Comment: Ah yeah. Thank you. Forgive my carelessness